# Add to iCloud Reading List from Chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ios, icloud

In Chrome (on Windows), how can I add a webpage to my iCloud Reading List to read later on my iPad?

My iOS devices (iPad, iPhone) are already set to synchronize their bookmarks via iCloud.

Answer (score 9):

It's clunky, but the best solution I've found so far:

Drag the URLs into Safari and add it to the reading list in Safari (which will synchronize with iCloud).

To synchronize your Safari bookmarks (including the Reading List) with iCloud:

1. Download and install Safari and the iCloud Control Panel for Windows (if you haven't already).
2. Use the iCloud Control Panel to choose to synchronize your iCloud bookmarks with Safari.

Comment: Automate the process with AutoHotkey, and you've got yourself a great solution. :)

Comment: Not a solution anymore as Safari is no longer supported on Windows.

Comment: Not clunky at all. On Mac just dragged the URL from Chrome to Safari icon in dock! Very elegant solution!

Answer (score 8):

Highlight the url in chrome.
**right-click** > **services** > **add to reading list**

Comment: This only works in OS X, right? The question is about Chrome in Windows.

Comment: My experience is that this doesn't even work as one would expect in OSX either. It just opens up Safari and stops there.

Answer (score 5):

Here ya go... Apple's Official Chrome extension (only works on Windows, as it's redundant on a Mac):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icloud-bookmarks/fkepacicchenbjecpbpbclokcabebhah

Additionally, there's some nice scripting goodies here for Chrome on OSX users:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51534/reading-list-in-other-browsers

Comment: This doesn't sync the reading list, only other bookmarks (from what I can tell).

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I use a work around for the same situation.

Read it later allows you to mark URL's to read later, storing them on their own cloud. The plus to this is that you can use an extension for Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari, iPhone, iPad... and access them anywhere. Very handy!

http://readitlaterlist.com/apps/chrome
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bkikpncfbjndhfkipijhdoddiadaipaa